# unknown operator error while running .sh file

Tags: solaris, ksh

this is my script where it is searching all the log files and zipping it alongwith deleting the older archive.
However, when i run this script i get the following error :

**./file.sh: test: unknown operator .**

Code:

```
#Directory of archives

archive_dr="/u01/apps/weblogic/weblogic10/user_projects/archive"

#Directory of log files

logdir="/u01/apps/weblogic/weblogic10/user_projects/domains/BPM/servers/BPM_MS1/logs"


cd $archive_dr

#Removing older archived files

if [ find . \( -name '*.log0*.gz' -o \
         -name '*.out0*.gz' \) ]
then
    rm *.out00*.gz *.log00*.gz
fi

cd $logdir

#Search,zip and move the new archive files

if [ find . \( -name '*.log0*' -o -name '*.out0*' \) \
          -atime +30 ]
then
    for log_files in `find . \( \
            -name '*.log0*' -o -name '*.out0*' \
        \) -atime +30`

    do
        gzip $log_files
        mv $log_files.gz /u01/a*/w*/w*/us*/archive
    done

    if [$? = 0]; then
        echo "Logs Archieved Successfully"|
        mailx -s " Logs Archieved Successfully" \
            -c 'x@abc.com' y@abc.com'
    fi
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
 if [ find . \( -name '*.log0*.gz' -o -name '*.out0*.gz' \) ]; then
```

to:

```
 if [ "$(find . \( -name '*.log0*.gz' -o -name '*.out0*.gz' \))" ]; then
```

You want to run the `find` command and test whether it returns any output. The `test` command (which is what `[` is an abbreviation for) doesn't execute its contents, it expects it to be an expression to test, as in `if [ "$foo" = 3 ]`.

Note also that `find` recurses into subdirectories, but you `rm` only in the current directory. If you don't want to recurse, add the `-maxdepth 1` option.

There's no need for the second `if`. If that `find` doesn't find any files, the `for` loop will have nothing to operate on and will just terminate immediately.

Comment: In addition to the above, you need a space between `[` and `$` on this line: `if [$? = 0]; then`, and another space after the `0` and before the `]` -- like this `if [ $? = 0 ]; then`.

Comment: I intentionally removed .gz files, now when i run the script it gives me that the .gz files are not found

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not able to edit the post properly. But, got it running , :)

**CODE**

```
#Directory of archives    
archive_dr="/u01/apps/weblogic/weblogic10/user_projects/archive"    

  #Directory of log files

 logdir="/u01/apps/weblogic/weblogic10/user_projects/domains"
   cd $archive_dr 
 #Removing older archived files
   find . \( -name '*.log00*.gz' -o -name '*.out00*.gz' \) -exec  rm {} \;

 cd $logdir

    #Search,zip and move the new archive files

for log_files in `find . \( -name '*.log0*' -o -name '*.out0*' \) -ctime +5`
    do

            gzip $log_files

            mv $log_files.gz /u01/a*/w*/w*/us*/archive

    done        
     if [ $? = 0 ]; then  

   echo "text"|mailx -s "test" -c abc@def.com' mno@pqr.com'  
 fi
```